# RHEL 8.1 how to install libssh2 1.9 and openssh 8.1 or higher

Tags: repository, rhel8

I need to upgrade my `libssh2` and `openssh` to newer versions.  Currently, I have `libssh2 v1.8` and `openssh v8.0` .  To pass compliance, both need updated but these are the only versions showing up in yum/dnf.

I read that the `CodeReady` repo would have the updated versions of both, but only the versions I have show up when I list available versions.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Below is my release info and repo list.  I'm not sure of what other information is needed so just let me know if I've left out something necessary.

```
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.1 (Ootpa)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.1"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.1 (Ootpa)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8.1:GA"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.1
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.1"
```

My repos

```
repo id                                                   repo name                                                                                        status
codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-x86_64-eus-rpms              Red Hat CodeReady Linux Builder for RHEL 8 x86_64 - Extended Update Support (RPMs)               1,859
codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-x86_64-eus-source-rpms       Red Hat CodeReady Linux Builder for RHEL 8 x86_64 - Extended Update Support (Source RPMs)          489
*epel                                                     Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64                                                   5,127
*epel-modular                                             Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64                                               0
remi-modular                                              Remi's Modular repository for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64                                          345
remi-safe                                                 Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64                                       2,143
rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms                                Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream from RHUI (RPMs)                               8,515
rhel-8-baseos-rhui-rpms                                   Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS from RHUI (RPMs)                                  3,697
rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms                          Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)                                         8,515
rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms                             Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS (RPMs)                                            3,697
rhui-client-config-server-8                               Red Hat Update Infrastructure 3 Client Configuration Server 8                                        7
```

**EDIT**

I just read that `libssh` replaces `libssh2`.  (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/considerations_in_adopting_rhel_8/index#literal_libssh2_literal_is_not_available_in_rhel_8)

I suppose the answer, then, is to just remove `libssh2` from the server instead as long as I have nothing that relies on it?

Answer (score 1):

libssh2 version **1.8** was in RHEL 8.0 and have been removed in 8.1

libssh2 version **1.9** is now in EPEL, in testing repository for now

But indeed, if you don't need it, you can remove it.

Comment: Thanks, do you know about the `openssh 8.1` by chance?